# Label Binarizer: Multiple Columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn

I am currently trying to convert the dataframe below:

```
0                Cat             Chicken
1                Fish            Chicken
2                Fish            Cat
3                Cat             Chicken
4                Dog             Cat
```

To

```
                Cat    Fish   Dog    Chicken
0                1      0      0      1     
1                0      1      0      1
2                1      1      0      0
3                1      0      0      1
4                1      0      1      0
```

So far I have only managed to successfully do Label Binarizer of singular columns. I can imagine doing this in a brute force manner where I loop through everything and check conditionally. However, that would cause the run time to be quite long. Therefore, is there a smarter way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df.apply(','.join,1).str.get_dummies(sep=',')
Out[51]: 
   Cat  Chicken  Dog  Fish
0    1        1    0     0
1    0        1    0     1
2    1        0    0     1
3    1        1    0     0
4    1        0    1     0
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `get_dummies` with prefix and prefix separator as empty strings i.e

```
pd.get_dummies(df,prefix='',prefix_sep='').groupby(level=0, axis=1).max() # Thanks @ coldspeed

     Cat  Chicken  Dog  Fish
0    1        1    0     0
1    0        1    0     1
2    1        0    0     1
3    1        1    0     0
4    1        0    1     0
```

Comment: `pd.get_dummies(df,prefix='',prefix_sep='').groupby(level=0, axis=1).max()`